# How can I get a list of symmetric polynomials?

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

**Q1:** Suppose I have an expression like this one:
$(1+x+y+z)^3$

How can I transform it into the following expression:
$$\{1,x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2,xy+xz+yz,x^3+y^3+z^3,x^2y+x^2z+xy^2+y^2z+xz^2+yz^2,xyz\}$$

**Q2:**  Suppose I have an expression like this one:
$(1+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^4$

How can I transform it into the following expression:
$$\{1,x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_4,x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_4^2,x_1x_2+x_1x_3+\cdots+x_3x_4,x_1^3+x_2^3+\cdots+x_4^3,x_1^2x_2+x_1^2x_3+\cdots+x_4^2x_3,x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+\cdots+x_2x_3x_4,x_1^4+x_2^4+\cdots+x_4^4,x_1^3x_2+x_1^3x_3+\cdots+x_4^3x_3,x_1^2x_2^2+x1^2x_3^2+\cdots+x_3^2x_4^2, x_1^2x_2x_3+x_1^2x_2x_4+\cdots+x_4^2x_2x_3, x_1x_2x_3x_4 \}$$

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please indicate if this is a Mathematica question. If so, I request you to include Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: If one groups the terms of the expansion of $(1+x_1+ x_2+ x_3)^3$ as you've requested, then some of those terms will have integer coefficients other than 1.  For example, do you really want to end up with $x_1 x_2 x_3$ rather than $6 x_1 x_2 x_3$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I would like to end with $x_1 x_2 x_3$ if possible.

Comment: Sounds good.  Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[symPolynomial]
symPolynomial[n_, sym_ : x] := Module[{v = Array[Subscript[sym, #] &, n], 
   ip = Join @@ (IntegerPartitions[#, {n}, Range[0, n]] & /@ Range[0, n])}, 
  FromCoefficientRules[Thread[Permutations[#] -> 1], v] & /@ ip]
```

***Examples:***

```
symPolynomial[3] // Column
```

[image]

```
symPolynomial[4] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @deltaxxkkk, my pleasure. Welcome to mmase.

Answer (score 1):

```
FactorTermsList /@ MonomialList[(1 + x + y + z)^3, {x, y, z}];
Total /@ SplitBy[SortBy[%[[All, 2]], #], #] &@
({Total@Exponent[#, {x, y, z}], Max@Exponent[#, {x, y, z}]} &)

(* {1, x + y + z, x y + x z + y z, x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x y z, 
 x^2 y + x y^2 + x^2 z + y^2 z + x z^2 + y z^2, x^3 + y^3 + z^3} *)
```

Maybe simpler:

```
SplitBy[SortBy[CoefficientRules[(1+x+y+z)^3][[All,1]],#],#]&@{Total,Max};
Flatten@Map[Total,Map[Times@@({x,y,z}^#)&,%,{3}],{2}]

(* {1,x+y+z,x y+x z+y z,x^2+y^2+z^2,x y z,x^2 y+x y^2+x^2 z+y^2 z+x z^2+y z^2,x^3+y^3+z^3} *)
```

Comment: Excellent!   Thank you very much.
Excuse me, May I ask you some question?

If possible, Could you tell me if (1+x+y+z)^5, (1+x+y+z+w)^4, (1+x+y+z+v+w)^5,...
I would like to know how to make a general list.
I apologize for my poor english.

Comment: If it answers your question you can accept it by clicking on icon on the left. Both codes should work in general case. Just replace `(1 + x + y + z)^3` with `(1+x+y+z+w)^4` and `{x,y,z}` with `{x,y,z,w}`.

Comment: I apologize again and again.  I edited the above question text by adding Q2, Q3.

Answer (score 1):

The function `AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial` will do most of the work.

```
list = {x, y, z};

n = Length[list];
temp = (AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial[#, list] &) /@ Flatten[IntegerPartitions[#] & /@ Range[n], 1]
(* {x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2,2 x y+2 x z+2 y z,x^3+y^3+z^3,x^2 y+x y^2+x^2 z+y^2 z+x z^2+y z^2,6 x y z} *)

(* Now get rid of the integer coefficients *)
temp = (temp // Expand) //. Times[t_, z_] /; IntegerQ[t] -> Times[z];
temp = Join[{1}, temp]
(* {1,x+y+z,x+y+z,x y+x z+y z,x+y+z,x y+x z+y z,x y z} *)
```

Comment: Great. It's great! Thank you!!! (I am so happy and excited!)

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]

f = Module[{p = #, v = Variables @ #}, 
     Values @
     GroupBy[Keys @ CoefficientRules[p, v, "NegativeDegreeLexicographic"], 
       Sort, 
       FromCoefficientRules[Thread[# -> 1], v] &]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f[(1 + x + y + z)^3]
```

[image]

```
f[(1 + x + y + z + w)^4]
```

[image]

```
f[Array[x, 7, 1, Plus[1, ##] &]^7] // Short[#, 20] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the Expand function, but that won't give you what you listed above!

```
Expand[(1 + x + y + z)^3]

1 + 3 x + 3 x^2 + x^3 + 3 y + 6 x y + 3 x^2 y + 3 y^2 + 3 x y^2 + y^3 + 3 z + 6 x z + 3 x^2 z + 6 y z + 6 x y z + 3 y^2 z + 3 z^2 + 3 x z^2 + 3 y z^2 + z^3
```

Comment: The question asked by the OP is `How can I transform...?`. This answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its a difficult problem, because GatherBy seems to call GreobnerBasis and runs into errors while gathering sums of exponents.

At least the MonomialList has an optional argument for degree ordering

```
 mn= MonomialList[(1 + x + y + z)^3, {x, y, z} , "DegreeLexicographic"]
 {x^3, 3 x^2 y, 3 x^2 z, 3 x y^2, 6 x y z, 3 x z^2, y^3, 3 y^2 z, 3 y z^2, z^3, 
 3 x^2, 6 x y, 6 x z, 3 y^2, 6 y z, 3 z^2, 
 3 x, 3 y,  3 z, 
 1}
```

Edit, Exponent is Listable:

```
   Plus@@@Gather[List@@Expand[(1+x+y+z)^3],
       Function[{f,g},Plus@@Exponent[f,{x,y,z}]==Plus@@Exponent[g,{x,y,z}]]]
```

Comment: There are unbalanced parentheses or braces. Can you please fix. Thanks.

Comment: Plus @@@ Gather[ List @@  Expand[(1 + x + y + z)^3], 
    Function[{f, g} , 
     Plus @@ Exponent[f, {x, y, z}] == Plus @@ Exponent[g, {x, y, z}] ]]

Comment: I don't think `GatherBy` calls `GroebnerBasis`.

Comment: Runningf a bit too deeply nest of pure functions in the test ended in an error reported by Groebner.

Comment: If you post the GatherBy example that gave the error I’ll look into it. My guess is the message has the wrong function tag.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable list is not large it can be done by symmetrizing monomials and using `DeleteDuplicates` in places to remove duplicates. The code below does no error checking and assumes there actually is a breakdown as a sum of symmetric polynomials.

```
sympPolys[poly_, vars_] := Module[
  {perms = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[Length[vars]]], 
   monoms = List @@ Expand[poly], sums},
  sums = Table[monom = monoms[[j]];
    Plus @@ 
     DeleteDuplicates[
      Map[monom /. 
         Thread[vars -> 
           vars[[PermutationReplace[Range[Length[vars]], #]]]] &, 
       perms]]
    , {j, Length[monoms]}];
  DeleteDuplicates[sums]
  ]
```

Example.

```
In[87]:= sympPolys[(1 + x + y + z)^5, {x, y, z}]

(* Out[87]= {1, 5 x + 5 y + 5 z, 10 x^2 + 10 y^2 + 10 z^2, 
 10 x^3 + 10 y^3 + 10 z^3, 5 x^4 + 5 y^4 + 5 z^4, x^5 + y^5 + z^5, 
 20 x y + 20 x z + 20 y z, 
 30 x^2 y + 30 x y^2 + 30 x^2 z + 30 y^2 z + 30 x z^2 + 30 y z^2, 
 20 x^3 y + 20 x y^3 + 20 x^3 z + 20 y^3 z + 20 x z^3 + 20 y z^3, 
 5 x^4 y + 5 x y^4 + 5 x^4 z + 5 y^4 z + 5 x z^4 + 5 y z^4, 
 30 x^2 y^2 + 30 x^2 z^2 + 30 y^2 z^2, 
 10 x^3 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 10 x^3 z^2 + 10 y^3 z^2 + 10 x^2 z^3 + 
  10 y^2 z^3, 60 x y z, 60 x^2 y z + 60 x y^2 z + 60 x y z^2, 
 20 x^3 y z + 20 x y^3 z + 20 x y z^3, 
 30 x^2 y^2 z + 30 x^2 y z^2 + 30 x y^2 z^2} *)
```